# How is this VW Bus beating my super car off the starting line?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

I have started playing more multiplayer in Forza Horizon 2 and came across a drag race game type.  I started with it with the following settings:

- Any Class
- Dry conditions
- Collisions on

I was racing in a hennessey venom gt at class X999 and the majority of my opponents were in similar super cars, except one.   He was in a VW Type 2 Bus... and he easily beat me off the starting line.  How is this possible?  I know you can manually configure your upgrades, but I use auto for most of my cars.   Is there an upgrade that would help me substantially?   All of my stats are at 10 except for handling.

Example: 
[image]

**VS**

[image]

Comment: If its anything like FM 5 (which it probably is), it's because of conversion kits. Stock equipment would never beat a Venom, but throw in a massive v8 + maxed out super charger + Rear wheel drive + fat back tires = nearly anything can become a drag monster. I'll have an answer after I do some toying around with my campervan

Comment: @Rapitor that would be awesome!  Let me know what you find out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment the answer to this unexpected powerhouse is conversion kits.

A stock Venom GT has the following stats:

```
1200 HorsePower
1,155 LB-FT of torque
3685 LBS of weight
6162 Displacement
2.5 seconds 0-60
5.3 seconds 0-100
270 MPH top speed
Rear Wheel Drive
```

Being a hypercar it doesn't have too many upgrades to squeeze out anymore than this so upping it to a class X doesn't even improve HorsePower, it just lowers the weight

A fully upgraded(I got from searching for a drag tune) VW Campervan has the following:

```
928 Horsepower
826 LB-FT of torque
2647 LBS of weight
7000 Displacement
2.4 seconds 0-60*
4.1 seconds 0-100*
201 MPH top speed
All Wheel Drive
```

*** I had to manually time this as using a shared tune does not allow you to see the detailed stats/dynamo**

As you can see... even though the Venom has much bigger numbers in horsepower, torque and top speed. It is much heavier... around a thousand pounds heavier, and upgrading it only takes off  around two hundred pounds. That will help slightly, but not enough. Giving the Venom AWD hurt it as you are unable to get more horsepower through upgrades, so even though the same amount of power was being used. the amount of *actual* power to each wheel is less.

The Campervan on the other hand has much lower HP, torque, and top speed. What makes it better is that it is lighter and has better [Displacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_displacement). These 2 factors (along with the proper tuning I can't see) allow it to have a faster 0-60 and a much faster 0-100, which is what matters in drag races. Being all wheel drive here is beneficial as since it is lighter, all 4 tires can use all of the power immediately without any slipping or traction trouble

**TL;DR Answer**: Conversion Kits, Upgrades, and Tuning allows nearly any vehicle to be competitive against hypercars and other "top of the line" vehicles